# Android - how can prevent a fragment from losing focus?

Tags: android

**Short version:**
how can prevent a fragment from losing focus?

**Long Version:**
I am overlaying 3 fragments on top of an existing activity using a fragment transaction.

[image: overlaying fragments]

Here you can see what it looks like.  Fragment C is the original fragment being displayed as part of the activity.  After a certain event I commit a transaction adding the new fragments:

```
ContainerFragment containerFragment = new ContainerFragment();
FragmentA aFragment = new FragmentA();
FragmentB bFragment = new FragmentB();
bFragment.setListener(listener);

FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.c_fragment, containerFragment, TAG_CONTAINER);

// added within the layout used by containerFragment

transaction.add(R.id.a_fragment, aFragment, TAG_A);
transaction.add(R.id.b_fragment, bFragment, TAG_B);

transaction.addToBackStack(TRANSACTION_NAME);
transaction.commit();
```

Note: I'm not using a separate activity to launch Fragments A and B because I don't want to pause the original activity.

Anyway, this works great.  The issue comes from the fact that I use the Dpad, and I can click the down button and the focus leaves Fragment A and selects something in Fragment C (Fragment B isn't focusable).  How can I prevent focus from leaving Fragment A?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For future references:

You can implement this by using something like this:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

   val parentView = view.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.container)
   getContainer().viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener { oldFocus, newFocus ->
            if (!getContainer().contains(newFocus) && oldFocus != null)
                oldFocus.requestFocus()
   }
}
```